# Retrieving all posts from a board that a user's subscribed to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm currently setting up a feed from scratch where a user subscribes to multiple message boards and would receive all of the posts created under that board. This is how I have my code written so far:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subscriptions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :boards, through: :subscriptions
end

class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :board
end

class Board < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subscriptions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :subscribers, through: :subscriptions, source: :user
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :board
  belongs_to :user
end
```

When it comes time to display the posts is where I'm having problems as far as the proper approach. Would the simple solution be to setup another HMT association in the user model as so?

```
has_many :subscribed_posts, through: :boards, source: :posts
```

One immediate flaw I see in my approach is that the user would get their posts to show up including those of other users. Would the better solution be to create some sort of SQL query?

Comment: Could you share your `posts`model?

Comment: @HDox Updated my question.

Comment: According to your model, you can retrieve all the `posts` under subscription board using this query.
`user.boards.includes(:posts).map(&:posts)`

Comment: Correct but note my concern of users also being able to retrieve the posts that they've written themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can build another association to retrieve posts you need, but as you mentioned that would return also the users' posts too, so you have to put some conditions to prevent such behavior.

```
has_many :subscribed_posts, through: :boards, source: :posts, conditions: {["user_id != ?", id] }
```

Comment: Wasn't aware that you were able to pass a `conditions` option in a `has_many` call. Thanks!